# My server run by systemd service but can't generate log file

Tags: linux, logging, server, watch, systemd

I used **systemd** (ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS) to start MyServer at service (if reboot or crash ocurred, restart automatically by systemd).
It's work fine but it's never generate logs any more!
My server generate logs at file "MyServerLogs" and if this file not exist, create new one (in same running directory).

Also MyServer watch a directory (that create by itself in same running directory) for file creation. This does not work either!

When MyServer run by systemd service, It can not create file, write to file and watch directory for file creation any more. But why?.

I develop MyServer with c++ and beginner of **systemd** and **unit files**.

I put MyServer at:

```
/usr/bin/MyServer
```

and my *unit file*

```
[Unit]
Description=Virtual Distributed Ethernet
After=syslog.target
After=network-online.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/MyServer
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just log to stdout/stderr instead of logging to a file. Don't create a log file in the current working directory, because it's probably not useful.  Instead, if you want to write a log file, allow it to be specified explicitly as a command line option or config file item or something.

Comment: what about watch directory?! why this does not work?!